# Squares dividing program not drawing

Tags: java, swing, for-loop

I am getting back into Java, and I am trying to make a program that has a square, which turns into for smaller equal squares, and those squares turn into 4 smaller squares and so on and so on, but when i try to run the program it doesn't do anything.

Here is my code:

```
package main;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class mainPanel extends JPanel {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")

    ArrayList rects = new ArrayList();

    int rectangles = 1;
    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;
    int size = 1000;

    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    int frames = 0;
    int fps = 0;

    public mainPanel() {
        setDoubleBuffered(true);
        rects.add(new cube(x, y, size));

        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (1 != 2) {
                    repaint();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        t.start();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        super.paint(g);

        Graphics g2 = g;

        for (int i = 0; i < rectangles; i++) {
            g.fillRect(x, y, size, size);

            size /= 4;
            x += size / 2 + 1;
            y += size / 2 + 1;
            rectangles += 4;
        }

        frames++;
        if (System.nanoTime() - lastTime >= 1000000000) {
            fps = frames;
            frames = 0;
            lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        }

        g.drawString("FPS: " + fps, 5, 15);
        g.dispose();
    }

}
```

When I run the program, even when I slow down the sleep function to 1000ms, no squares are drawn at all, and over time my fps slows down alot.

Comment: Remember, Swing is not thread safe ;), also calling `dispose` on `Graphics` context you didn't create can produce side effects (like not painting anything to the screen), so be careful

Comment: What's `cube`?  Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: You could use a Swing `Timer` instead of an infinite loop AND you should only ever paint the state of the component, paint methods should contain as little logic as possible.

Comment: I think the biggest issue you have is not realising that painting in Swing (and in fact most GUIs) is destructive, not compounding. Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting is done..